# When the checkbox is not selected, the "input" and "select" options are still calculating, and result NAN error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem with code, when checkbox is selected the total sum still trying take value from input from select and input boxes (which are located inside of checkbox) and final NAN error

```
function calculate(){
    var d = parseFloat($('#wall_t').val());
    var ww = parseFloat($('#fasadwidth').val());//"input option" inside checkbox
    var wh = parseFloat($('#fasadhigh').val());//"input option" inside checkbox
    var wq = parseFloat($('#wqt').val());//"select option" inside checkbox
    var wt = parseFloat($('#windowtype').val());//"select option" inside checkbox
    
    var str3 = ""
    var sumW = 0;
    $(':checkbox').each(function() {
    str3 += this.checked ? "1," : "0,";
    });

    if ($('#ff1').is(":checked"))
    {
    sumW += ff1;
    }

    var sumW = wh * (ww * wq);
    var sum = d * sumW * wt;

    $('#result').text(sum);
    console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat().format(sum).text('VT'));

};
```

Here is my checkbox if selected are showing input and select options.

```
function openFasad(){   
    let fasadForm = $('#fasad-form');
    if (fasadForm.hasClass('n-none')) {
        fasadForm.removeClass('n-none');
    } else {
        fasadForm.addClass('n-none');
    }
}
```